# How to delete multiple process id of a single process?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, kill

I'm using the following code to kill all the PID's of a certain process, but its not working as expected.

```
pgrep -f <processname>

kill -9 $(pgrep -f <processname>)
```

when there are more than one PID, the above line throws error stating :

> too many arguments.

Comment: What if you remove the `-f`?  That exact same command (except for the `-f`) works for me in killing Chromium.

Comment: A little nitpick: there's no such thing as "multiple process IDs of a single process". Each process has one PID. (Unless you count its threads, which I don't) What this question is about is killing all the processes with a certain command, or rather all processes with commands that match a certain pattern of text.  It might be clearer for readers to change the wording accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
killall <processname>
```

`killall` allows killing all processes by name or even regexes (`-r`) and a few other options for matching the correct group of processes. `SIGTERM` options are available (`killall -9 name`).

Answer (score 4):

That's what `pkill` is for:

```
pkill -f <processname>
```

Or, if you *must* use `-9`:

```
pkill -9 -f <processname>
```

---

In order to do what you were attempting, you would need to pass the *output* of the `pgrep` command to `kill`. Instead, you are passing a *variable* named `$pgrep` which, of course, has no value. You can see this by running the command after enabling `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ kill -9 $pgrep -f emacs
+ kill -9 -f emacs
sh: kill: -f: arguments must be process or job IDs
sh: kill: emacs: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

(run `set +x` to disable debugging info)

As you can see above, the `$pgrep` was removed since it is an undefined variable, and therefore empty, and the `-f` and `emacs` were passed as arguments to `kill`. What you wanted to do was use [*command substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) to pass the output of one command as input to another:

```
kill $(pgrep -f emacs)
```

Finally, avoid using `kill -9 foo` unless it is absolutely necessary and `kill foo` alone doesn't work. Using `-9` can be quite destructive and doesn't let the process exit gracefully.

Comment: I tried "pkill -f <processname>" and that was not working in my case. so I posted the question here. as per your suggestion using "pkill -9 -f <processname>" worked